# Trying to create a view using css flexbox, combining row and columns

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to create the layout shown in the diagram below with css flex, I am part way there but need to help with the 3 boxes on the right and the box on the bottom, can anyone help?

layout view needed:

[image: png layout view needed]

this is how far i got: [my attempt on the view on jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zincy/4k9ukau0/)

```
.game-heading{background: #a3a3a3;}
header{
  display: flex;
}
article{
  display: flex;
}
.scores {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex: 1;
    line-height: 1;
}
.period {
    background: #c29d31;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    text-align: center;
}

.results{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.score-nr {
    background: #9E8231;
    flex: 1;
    line-height: 10px;
    padding: 6px;
}
.competitors{
    color: #2d2929;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    float: left;
    flex-grow: 0;
}

.fa {
    align-self: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
.venue-content{
  background: #a3a3a3;
  width: 100%
}

h4{
  display: inline-flex;
}
.competitor-name {
  padding: 4px;
}
ul li{
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #808080;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a start, where I moved the `ft-container` inside the `header`, positioned before the `venue-content`.

Then, by splitting the `ul` into to 2 `ul`, you can easily line them up side-by-side, adding `display: flex` to the `ft-container`.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4k9ukau0/1/)

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.game-heading {
  background: #a3a3a3;
}

header {
  display: flex;
}

article {
  display: flex;
}

.scores {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
  line-height: 1;
}

.period {
  background: #c29d31;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.score-nr {
  background: #9E8231;
  flex: 1;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 6px;
}

.competitors {
  color: #2d2929;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  float: left;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.fa {
  align-self: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.venue-content {
  background: #a3a3a3;
  width: 100%
}

h4 {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.competitor-name {
  padding: 4px;
}

/*  styles below have been changed/added  */

ul li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
ul {
  border: 1px solid #808080;
}

.ft-container {
  display: flex;
}
.ft-container ul:last-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section class="container-one-row two">
  <h3 class="game-heading">game type </h3>
  <article class="game-content">
    <header class="event-title">
      <div class="scores">
        <span class="period">Time</span>
        <div class="results">
          <span class="score-nr">5122</span>
          <span class="score-nr">8213</span>
        </div>
        <div class="competitors">
          <h3 class="competitor-name">jimmy1234</h3>
          <h3 class="competitor-name">player98763</h3>
        </div>
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>

        <section class="ft-container">
          <ul>
            <li>222
            </li>
            <li>543
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul>
            <li>mid
            </li>
          </ul>
        </section>

        <div class="venue-content">
          <h4>Neutral</h4>
          <i class=" fa fa-gamepad"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
  </article>
</section>
```

---

Updated based on a comment saying, *can't move the `ft-container`'s markup*

Then you needed to use absolute positioning, to position the `ft-container` at the right, and match its height against the `competitors`, which in itself need to match the `ft-container` and *arrow* to avoid a wrap.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4k9ukau0/2/)

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.game-heading {
  background: #a3a3a3;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

article {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.scores {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
  line-height: 1;
}

.period {
  background: #c29d31;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.results {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.score-nr {
  background: #9E8231;
  flex: 1;
  line-height: 10px;
  padding: 6px;
}

.competitors {
  color: #2d2929;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

.fa {
  align-self: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.venue-content {
  background: #a3a3a3;
  width: 100%;
}

h4 {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.competitor-name {
  padding: 4px;
}

ul li {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}

ul {
  border: 1px solid #808080;
}

.ft-container {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 44px;
  display: flex;
}

.ft-container ul:last-child {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section class="container-one-row two">
  <h3 class="game-heading">game type </h3>
  <article class="game-content">
    <header class="event-title">
      <div class="scores">
        <span class="period">Time</span>
        <div class="results">
          <span class="score-nr">5122</span>
          <span class="score-nr">8213</span>
        </div>
        <div class="competitors">
          <h3 class="competitor-name">jimmy1234</h3>
          <h3 class="competitor-name">player98763</h3>
        </div>
        <i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i>

        <div class="venue-content">
          <h4>Neutral</h4>
          <i class=" fa fa-gamepad"></i>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <section class="ft-container">
      <ul>
        <li>222
        </li>
        <li>543
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul>
        <li>mid
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </article>
</section>
```

Comment: I notice you assigned 222, 543 and mid all as list items of the UL. if you make a second UL and include mid in it's list item. you can simply make them equal the same height should fix your problem.

Comment: @MarshallMunoz They were already list items, so I simply kept them as such, and leave to the OP to either change or keep them as is, and it was asked for to have them in 2 columns

Comment: Whoops my comment was for OP your code looks exactly like what I was meaning to tell OP good job!

Comment: thanks all, i can do that change for the second ul, has anyone got an idea how to get the "neutral" line to start under the player and go all the way across?

Comment: @zincy Added a 2nd sample based on not being able to move the `ft-container`